# How to set all the four axes with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5BbL.png]

I want to draw a picture like this one, the top and right axes have different labels and ticks, anyone can help me?

Comment: Check the docs! https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both datasets are completely independent, one would probably not use twin axes here. Instead, just use two different axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
x1 = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y1 = np.random.rand(11)
x2 = np.linspace(1,0,101)
y2 = np.random.rand(101)*20+20


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="second axes")
ax2.set_facecolor("none")

ax1.set_xlabel('x1', color='red')
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', color='red')
ax1.plot(x1, y1, color='red')
ax1.tick_params(colors='red')

ax2.set_xlabel('x2', color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', color='blue')
ax2.plot(x2, y2, color='blue')
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax2.tick_params(colors='blue')

for which in ["top", "right"]:
    ax2.spines[which].set_color("blue")
    ax1.spines[which].set_visible(False)
for which in ["bottom", "left"]:
    ax1.spines[which].set_color("red")
    ax2.spines[which].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To double both axes you have to use `ax1.twinx().twiny()`.

Here an example:

```
# Create some mock data
x1 = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y1 = [random.randint(1,5) for n in x1]
#print(x1,y1)

x2 = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
y2 = [random.randint(10,50) for n in x2]
#print(x2,y2)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_xlabel('x1', color='red')
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', color='red')
ax1.plot(x1, y1, color='red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx().twiny() #here is the trick!

ax2.set_xlabel('x2', color='blue')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', color='blue')
ax2.plot(x2, y2, color='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', labelcolor='blue') #y2 does not get blue... can't yet figure out why

plt.show()
```

Here the result:

[image]

Comment: The plot is okay, but I can't figure out how to fix the color and the label on the second Y axes. If someone knows how to, please comment!

Comment: The construct `ax1.twinx().twiny()` is not very useful, because it hides the fact that you have now 3 axes. Use `ax2=ax1.twinx(); ax3=ax2.twiny()` and format each of `ax2` and `ax3` to your liking.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Where would you plot then? On ax2 or ax3? It's a bit confusing, can you add an answer with an example?

Comment: You would plot on `ax3` just as you do here, but you will have a handle to `ax2` to be able to format or colorize it. As I personally wouldn't use twin axes for this kind of problem anyways (There is no twinning needed, both curves are entirely independent), I'm not going to provide any such answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `twinx` and `twiny` functions, take a look at [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html)